# pregmatch for numbers only

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to use preg_match to extract numbers only. I have tried the fllowing code but it does not work. Any ideas how to only get the number?

```
preg_match_all('/^[0-9]+$/i', '<userinfo>Jsome text here 16586 more text here.</userinfo>', $result);
```

Comment: Don't use [anchors](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.anchors.php).

Comment: What do you want to happen if the string contains a float like `"This costs $1.23"`? Do you want to capture `1` and `23` or not? If not, how will you decide where a number starts/ends?

Comment: it will always be consecutive numbers no . or ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the regular expression you should be using:

```
/<userinfo>.*?(\d+).*?<\/userinfo>/
```

This will match

```
<userinfo>Jsome text here 16586 more text here.</userinfo>
```

and the 2nd element of the returned array (`array[1]`) will have the number you need. (16586)

Comment: did a var_dump and it only returns 6 the 2nd number of the number string

Comment: Works really slow! If inside `<userinfo>` you want to match only one number it had better use this one regexp `'#<userinfo>(?:\D+|(\d+))+</userinfo>#i'`. But if you want to match all numbers inside that tag you should use something else

Answer (score 0):

Your regex shouldn't include the `^` and `$` symbols, as they denote the start and end of the string, which doesn't exist in the middle of a string.

Take them out and the regex should work just fine.

Comment: i have to match between <userinfo> like this `\<userinfo\>\d+\<\/userinfo\>`

Answer (score 0):

The symbol `^` specify the beggening of the line and `$` - line end. So your RegExp completely wrong. You should write

```
preg_match_all('/\d+/', '<userinfo>Jsome text here 16586 more text here.</userinfo>', $result);
```

Also you do not need to specify `i` modificator, that means searching with case ignore mode.

Comment: thanks is there a way to make this work? `\<userinfo\>\d+\<\/userinfo\>`

Answer (score 0):

You have used `^` and `$` in your regular expression.  `^` means *match the start of the string* and `$` means *match the end of the string*.  As such, you've written a regex to match a string that contains only a number; i.e. your regex says *start of string* then *number* then *end of string*.  Remove these characters and you'll be able to match a number.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
preg_match_all('[0-9]+', '<userinfo>Jsome text here 16586 more text here.</userinfo>', $result);
```